# Sync contacts with mountain lion mac contact list

Tags: data-synchronization, contacts, mac-address

How do I sync mountain lion contact list to yahoo contact list?

Answer (score 2):

This is explained in detail on the [yahoo! help page](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_CLASSIC&locale=en_US&id=SLN3627).

I'll post the [original text](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_CLASSIC&locale=en_US&id=SLN3627) from the help page here:

> **Description**
>
> This article explains how to synchronize your Mac OS Address Book app to Yahoo! Contacts on your Mac for versions of Mac OS X 10.5 ("Leopard") and newer.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> You can sync Yahoo! Contacts with Mac Address Book.
>
> **Note:** Only Mac OS X 10.5 ("Leopard") and newer support the sync feature. To check what version of Mac OS X you've got, select the Apple | About This Mac.
>
> **How to sync your contacts with Mac Address Book:**
>
> 1. Open the Mac OS Address Book app.
> 2. Go to Address Book | Preferences.
> 3. Select Accounts | On My Mac.
> 4. Check the checkbox for Synchronize with Yahoo!.
> 5. Tap Agree for the Terms of Service.
> 6. Type your Yahoo! ID in the Yahoo! ID box.
> 7. Type your password in the Password box.
> 8. Tap OK.